# python monkey patch a new class and import it

Tags: python, monkeypatching

I want to monkey patch a new class and then import that class but I get an error ModuleNotFoundError. At the same time I can use the new patched function. I believe that I miss how to add it in the "**init**" file.

See the following simplified example:

```
import numpy
class wrong_functions():
    def wrong_add(num1, num2):
        return num1 + num2 + 1

numpy.random.wrong_functions = wrong_functions
numpy.random.wrong_functions.wrong_add(1,1) # works
from numpy.random.wrong_functions import wrong_add # does not work
from numpy.random.wrong_functions import * # does not work
```

What do you think? Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of the [import system](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html).

Reading through the doc, you can find this paragraph:

> [...] the statement `from spam.ham import eggs, sausage as saus` results in
>
> ```py
> _temp = __import__('spam.ham', globals(), locals(), ['eggs', 'sausage'], 0)
> eggs = _temp.eggs
> saus = _temp.sausage
> ```

The problem is: what does `__import__()` does?

> The `import` statement combines two operations; it searches for the named module, then it binds the results of that search to a name in the local scope. [...]
>
> A direct call to `__import__()` performs only the module search and, if found, the module creation operation.

So, when you re-import the module, your customization will be lost.

To ensure it stays on, you can `import numpy as np` and then, when using `np` - after you assing this new class - you can always access `wrong_add`.

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.random.wrong_functions = wrong_functions
>>> np.random.wrong_function.wrong_add(1, 1)
3
```

EDIT: If you need/want to just call `wrong_add` instead of full package path to function, you can always assign it to a variable.

```py
>>> wrong_add = np.random.wrong_function.wrong_add
>>> wrong_add(2, 2)
5
```